# LIKE a control on a form with (less than greater than) in query criteria

Tags: ms-access

I more or less need to add this as a filter option of a calculated field. It's on a form with a search function that runs a query. I'm attempting to consolidate all the queries from the previous creator into one query. This is the only step I'm missing.

If I made that control a combo box and put as the row source

```
<5;<15;<30
```

Ideally, I'd like it to be <5; 15>x>5; 30>x>15 but I'm not sure how I can write that where the query can see if it's like that control.

```
Criteria Like "*" & [Forms]![FRM_SearchMulti]![txtClosing] & "*"
```

Comment: Are you trying to find where a number is `<5` or where a text `= "<"` ?

Comment: Number, the result is always an integer.

Answer (score 0):

I reckon you can build the string in VBA for speed, or use a UDF if you do not care about related queries failing or speed.

```
 Dim qdf As queryDef
 Set qdf = CurrentDB.QueryDefs("TempQuery") ''TempQuery must exist
 sSQL = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ANumber " & Me.MyCombo 
 qdf.SQL = sSQL

 DoCmd.OpenQuery qdf.Name
```

Or there abouts.